# Can wget download files that are uploaded to a website?

Tags: linux, wget

I tried using the "mirror" keyword to just grab everything, however it doesn't actually download files that are uploaded to the page. Is there a keyword that will tell it to download these files without specifying the file names?
The website hosting our files is a wiki called MoinMoin.

EDIT:
The picture below shows that when wget was run, it downloaded one of the pages from the wiki called "Logbook" which has several files saved on it. One which is called "Window_Transmission.PDF" simply appears as html code as a link, rather than actually downloading the files themselves. What I am looking for is to download these saved files, as well as the website itself. [image]

Comment: Please could you explain a little more. The `--mirror` option will copy an entire tree of files, so if you're not getting the files you want you need to review their URLs - which you should be able to determine from the HTML page source.

Answer (score 4):

What wget can download depends on what the web server offers for download.

In general a web server can allow uploads without allowing anyone to download those files again. There might also be a delay (e.g. if the owner of the website has to approve the content) before it can be downloaded.

The `--mirror` argument to `wget` just makes it analyse the webpage you ask it to download and then download everything linked from that, so it's also possible that the web server just doesn't add alink to the new files for downloading them, while it would technically be possible.

And when I say "web server" I mean "the software running on the web server".

So no general answer can be given. I don' know much about MoinMoin, but I believe it's advanced enough that it can be configured in ways so what you want is possible and in ways where it's impossible.

Comment: Thank you. It sounds like I need to dig around and see if MoinMoin allows this kind of downloading. I don't know if my modified question is any more illuminating.